# How to dump the data from file to an excel sheet

Tags: python, excel

I want to dump [3-4 lines together] some data to an excel sheet.
I could able to dump single line based on some criteria [like if line is getting start with // or /* ], but in case of when lines starts from /* and after 3-4 sentences its end with * / .
Only first line which is started from /* and last line which is ended with */ could able to dump.
I'm unable to handle this situation, please help.

Below is my code:-

```
fileopen = open("test.c")         
for var in fileopen:   
if var.startswith("//"):    
   var1 = var1 + var  
   continue  
 if var.startswith("/*"):  
   var1 = var1 + var  
   continue    

 else:  
   continue  
worksheet.write(i, 5,var1,cell_format)
```

Note:- Above code will be having indentation issue. As i don't how to put the code properly in stack over flow, so please ignore this issue.

For example:-
    /* Test that the correct data prefetch instructions are generated for i386
    variants that use 3DNow! prefetchw or SSE prefetch instructions with
    locality hints.  */

I want to dump entire data at once through python script but i could able to dump only "First Line", which is started with /*.

Any suggestion please!!!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This is python right? Excel users without any knowledge of python won't be able to answer you and it can take a while before one sees your question. If yes, then you need to add the python tag as well. Otherwise, add any relevant tags.

Comment: Use the following line from ostermiller for building the needed regex: http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html

Comment: Yes, i want to dump the data in to excel sheet through python script.

Comment: Thanks David C. Rankin for your suggestion.but its not working in python, getting error like "Invalid expression".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import re

fileopen = open("test.c")

# Convert file to a string
source_code = ""
for var in fileopen:
    source_code += var

# Find the first comment from the source code
pattern = r'//.*?$|/\*.*?\*/|\'(?:\\.|[^\\\'])*\'|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"'
var1 = re.search(pattern, source_code, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE).group() # first comment

var1 = unicode(var1, errors='ignore')
worksheet.write(i, 5, var1, cell_format)
```

Comment: Thanks alot for reply.its working fine but not met my requirement. As i need to fetch the comments line before stats the actual c code.If the comments in between of code that should not suppose to come and if there is no comments in begging [before actual starts], then controller should come out.. Thats All !!

Comment: @AnshuSharma, updated the code to search the first comment only as there's no definite way to predict where your C code starts. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks @ user1492071:, I did the same same but got **"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 18: invalid start byte"** error.  Any suggestion please ???

Comment: @AnshuSharma, the error is certainly thrown because of the excel interfacing module which you haven't specified. You can easily ignore invalid bytes by `unicode(var1, errors='ignore')`

Comment: Thanks again @ user1492071.i have added **unicode(var1, errors='ignore')** this code but still getting same error. and one more qus, How to specify excel interface module ??. i have imported **xlsxwriter** python pkg. Is that fine ??

Comment: May be i have added **unicode(var1, errors='ignore')** at wrong place.i have tried to add this code before,after and inside the **for loop** too but result is same.Could you please tell me where exactly i should add **unicode(var1, errors='ignore') ** this..? ?

Comment: `worksheet.write(i, 5, unicode(var1, errors='ignore'), cell_format)`

Answer (score 0):

This VBA reads a text file and dumps all comment lines to the first worksheet

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim iFN As Integer
    Dim sLine As String
    Dim iMultiple As Integer
    Dim sComment As String
    Dim iRow As Integer

    iFN = FreeFile()
    iMultiple = 0
    sComment = ""
    iRow = 1

    'Change this path as required
    Open "d:\temp\xl.txt" For Input As #iFN

    While Not EOF(iFN)
        sLine = ""
        Line Input #iFN, sLine
        If iMultiple = 1 Then
            sComment = sComment & sLine
            If Left(sLine, 2) = "*/" Then
                iMultiple = 0
            End If
        Else
            If Left(sLine, 2) = "//" Then
                sComment = sLine
            ElseIf Left(sLine, 2) = "/*" Then
                sComment = sLine
                iMultiple = 1

            End If
        End If
        If iMultiple = 0 And Trim(sComment) <> "" Then
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(iRow, 1).Value2 = sComment
            iRow = iRow + 1
            sComment = ""
        End If
    Wend
    Close #iFN
    MsgBox "Done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: I believe the op requires the solution in python.