# How to dump data from the file to excel sheet through python script?

Tags: python, excel

I want to dump [3-4 lines together] some data to an excel sheet.
I could able to dump single line based on some criteria [like if line is getting start with // or /* ], but in case of when lines starts from /* and after 3-4 sentences its end with * / .
Only first line which is started from /* and last line which is ended with */ could able to dump.
I'm unable to handle this situation, please help.

Below is my code:-

```
fileopen = open("test.c")         
for var in fileopen:   
if var.startswith("//"):    
   var1 = var1 + var  
   continue  
 if var.startswith("/*"):  
   var1 = var1 + var  
   continue    

 else:  
   continue  
worksheet.write(i, 5,var1,cell_format)
```

Note:- Above code will be having indentation issue. As i don't how to put the code properly in stack over flow, so please ignore this issue.

For example:-
        /* Test that the correct data prefetch instructions are generated for i386
        variants that use 3DNow! prefetchw or SSE prefetch instructions with
        locality hints.  */

I want to dump entire data at once through python script but i could able to dump only "First Line", which is started with /*.

Any suggestion please!!!
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which packages you are using for working with excel ? here are the available packages http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dump the data from file to an excel sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24278093/how-to-dump-the-data-from-file-to-an-excel-sheet)

Comment: Thanks @PavanGupta. I'm using "xlsxwriter" package. I think problem with how to fetch the data, not with excel pkg.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

fileopen = open("test.c")

# Convert file to a string
source_code = ""
for var in fileopen:
    source_code += var

# Find all the comments from the source code
pattern = r'//.*?$|/\*.*?\*/|\'(?:\\.|[^\\\'])*\'|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"'
found = re.findall(pattern, source_code, re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE) # list of comments

var1 = ""
for var in found:
    var1 = var1 + var

worksheet.write(i, 5,var1,cell_format)
```